# Mouse wheel events not fired when focus on map element INSIDE winform web browser

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

i'm displaying a openlayers map inside a **winform web browser**,
since i'm getting focused on map element(with a click on the map), i have not getting mouse wheel events any more,even not document mousewheel event, to start getting the events again i need to click on some other element rather than a map element.
when the app is running outside of the web browser(in IE,chrome,Firefox) everything working fine.
Has anyone seen a similar problem?

Comment: Yes, countless times, for countless reasons. Most likely you have a Javascript error somewhere. Without a minimum working example, it is likely to be rather hard to diagnose.

Comment: As i said, everything working fine in a browser, the problem is **winform web browser**. i have no errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is because losing focus on the map inside winform.  You can use `yourBrowserControl.Document.Focus()` to re-focus on the map after any of your c# actions and you will get your mouse wheel control back.

In my case, I used `splitContainer` to split the screen and I used the following code which works out great.  Every time when I click on the map, it will gain the focus back to the map, then the mouse wheel will work.

```
// add event hander
this.splitContainerMain.Panel2.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.splitContainerMain_Panel2_Enter);

// handler method
private void splitContainerMain_Panel2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (webBrowserMap.Document != null)
    webBrowserMap.Document.Focus();
}
```